# Debug Eclipse: Class File Editor source not found

Tags: spring, eclipse, debugging, servlets

Output:
The JAR file  C:\Users\segreteria.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.4.jar has no source attachment. You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below:

Perhaps, I suppose the mistake lies in the fact that
A few days ago I excluded some files from the pom that were not used, but now I would like to re-insert them, but there is no typing "< exclusions > " in the pom file. I reintegrated the 'spring-boot-devtools.2.7.4.jar' file but nothing has changed.
I tried to reintegrate it in all ways, from the pom, importing the jar, I also imported the jar sources file, the file is also present in the jdk, I imported it from a folder outside the repository, but the result remained unchanged.
thanks to who helps me.

test debug without breakpoint:
[image: test debug without breakpoint]
[image: test debug without breakpoint]
[image: test debug without breakpoint]

```
    OUTPUT CONSOLE:

09:40:27.682 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloa
der.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.dev
tools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@ff00a5

. ____ _ __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __ __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/ ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| | ) ) ) )
' |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot :: (v2.7.4)

2022-10-26 09:40:33.069 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] com.giuggiola.Parlament
oApplication : Starting ParlamentoApplication using Java 18.0.2.1 on UTENTE
-4KLNCD55 with PID 2868 (C:\Users\segreteria\Desktop\BACKUP pARLAMENTO\Parlament
o\target\classes started by segreteria in C:\Users\segreteria\Desktop\BACKUP pAR
LAMENTO\Parlamento)
2022-10-26 09:40:33.080 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] com.giuggiola.Parlament
oApplication : The following 1 profile is active: "@spring.profiles.active@
"
2022-10-26 09:40:33.714 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefa
ultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-
properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-10-26 09:40:33.715 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefa
ultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'log
ging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-10-26 09:40:42.859 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict reposito
ry configuration mode
2022-10-26 09:40:42.877 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Elasticsearch repositories in DEFA
ULT mode.
2022-10-26 09:40:43.401 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .RepositoryConfiguratio
nExtensionSupport : Spring Data Elasticsearch - Could not safely identify store
assignment for repository candidate interface com.giuggiola.repository.Parlament
areRepository; If you want this repository to be a Elasticsearch repository, con
sider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframewor
k.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document (preferred), or consider extending one
of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.elasticse
arch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository, org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.
repository.ElasticsearchRepository
2022-10-26 09:40:43.419 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .RepositoryConfiguratio
nExtensionSupport : Spring Data Elasticsearch - Could not safely identify store
assignment for repository candidate interface com.giuggiola.repository.RangeRepo
sitory; If you want this repository to be a Elasticsearch repository, consider a
nnotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.
elasticsearch.annotations.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the
following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.re
pository.ElasticsearchRepository, org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.reposit
ory.ElasticsearchRepository
2022-10-26 09:40:43.432 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 544 ms. Found 0
Elasticsearch repository interfaces.
2022-10-26 09:40:43.446 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict reposito
ry configuration mode
2022-10-26 09:40:43.449 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive Elasticsearch repositorie
s in DEFAULT mode.
2022-10-26 09:40:43.465 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .RepositoryConfiguratio
nExtensionSupport : Spring Data Reactive Elasticsearch - Could not safely identi
fy store assignment for repository candidate interface com.giuggiola.repository.
ParlamentareRepository; If you want this repository to be a Reactive Elasticsear
ch repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations:
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document (preferred), or cons
ider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframew
ork.data.elasticsearch.repository.ReactiveElasticsearchRepository
2022-10-26 09:40:43.477 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .RepositoryConfiguratio
nExtensionSupport : Spring Data Reactive Elasticsearch - Could not safely identi
fy store assignment for repository candidate interface com.giuggiola.repository.
RangeRepository; If you want this repository to be a Reactive Elasticsearch repo
sitory, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.spr
ingframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document (preferred), or consider ex
tending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.dat
a.elasticsearch.repository.ReactiveElasticsearchRepository
2022-10-26 09:40:43.481 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 31 ms. Found 0 R
eactive Elasticsearch repository interfaces.
2022-10-26 09:40:43.564 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict reposito
ry configuration mode
2022-10-26 09:40:43.580 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-10-26 09:40:43.826 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 216 ms. Found 2
JPA repository interfaces.
2022-10-26 09:40:51.212 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat
.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-10-26 09:40:51.458 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.
StandardService : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-10-26 09:40:51.459 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.cor
e.StandardEngine : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-10-26 09:40:53.824 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] org.apache.jasper.servl
et.TldScanner : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs.
Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scan
ned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can i
mprove startup time and JSP compilation time.
2022-10-26 09:40:54.091 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[loc
alhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-10-26 09:40:54.096 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerA
pplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2037
5 ms
2022-10-26 09:40:56.402 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.interna
l.util.LogHelper : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-10-26 09:40:57.038 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version
: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.11.Final
2022-10-26 09:40:58.075 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations
.common.Version : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-10-26 09:40:58.834 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.Hikar
iDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-10-26 09:41:00.384 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.Hikar
iDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-10-26 09:41:00.560 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.D
ialect : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10
Dialect
2022-10-26 09:41:03.835 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] Hibernate Types
: This framework is proudly powered by:

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
_ _ _ _
| | | | (_) | |
| |__| |_ _ _ __ ___ _ __ ___ _ ___| |_ ___ _ __ ___ ___
| __ | | | | '_ \ / _ \ '__/ __| / __| __/ _ \ '_ \ / __/ _ \
| | | | |_| | |_) | __/ | \__ \ \__ \ || __/ | | | (_| __/
|_| |_|\__, | .__/ \___|_| |___/_|___/\__\___|_| |_|\___\___|
__/ | |
|___/|_|

At Hypersistence, we only build amazing tools, like Hibernate Types, Flexy Pool,
or Hypersistence Optimizer.

What if there were a tool that could automatically detect JPA and Hibernate perf
ormance issues?

Hypersistence Optimizer is that tool! For more details, go to:

https://vladmihalcea.com/hypersistence-optimizer/
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

2022-10-26 09:41:06.840 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatfo
rmInitiator : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.
engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-10-26 09:41:06.883 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityM
anagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'd
efault'
2022-10-26 09:41:08.996 WARN 2868 --- [ restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$Jp
aWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, da
tabase queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spri
ng.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-10-26 09:41:09.700 DEBUG 2868 --- [ restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMapp
ingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1
RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2022-10-26 09:41:10.148 DEBUG 2868 --- [ restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMapp
ingHandlerMapping : 12 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2022-10-26 09:41:10.249 DEBUG 2868 --- [ restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleU
rlHandlerMapping : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2022-10-26 09:41:10.299 DEBUG 2868 --- [ restartedMain] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandler
ExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyA
dvice
2022-10-26 09:41:14.389 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveR
eloadServer : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-10-26 09:41:15.248 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat
.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-10-26 09:41:15.302 INFO 2868 --- [ restartedMain] com.giuggiola.Parlament
oApplication : Started ParlamentoApplication in 47.464 seconds (JVM running
for 61.457)

OUTPUT STACKTRACE:

// Compiled from SilentExitExceptionHandler.java (version 1.8 : 52.0, super bit)
class org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler implements java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler {

// Field descriptor #33 Ljava/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler;
private final java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler delegate;

// Method descriptor #35 (Ljava/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler;)V
// Stack: 2, Locals: 2
SilentExitExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler delegate);
0 aload_0 [this]
1 invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]
4 aload_0 [this]
5 aload_1 [delegate]
6 putfield org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler.delegate : java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler [2]
9 return
Line numbers:
[pc: 0, line: 33]
[pc: 4, line: 34]
[pc: 9, line: 35]
Local variable table:
[pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler
[pc: 0, pc: 10] local: delegate index: 1 type: java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
Method Parameters:
delegate

// Method descriptor #43 (Ljava/lang/Thread;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 3
public void uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread thread, java.lang.Throwable exception);
0 aload_2 [exception]
1 instanceof org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler$SilentExitException [3]
4 ifne 27
7 aload_2 [exception]
8 instanceof java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [4]
11 ifeq 40
14 aload_2 [exception]
15 checkcast java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [4]
18 invokevirtual java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.getTargetException() : java.lang.Throwable [5]
21 instanceof org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler$SilentExitException [3]
24 ifeq 40
27 aload_0 [this]
28 aload_1 [thread]
29 invokespecial org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler.isJvmExiting(java.lang.Thread) : boolean [6]
32 ifeq 39
35 aload_0 [this]
36 invokevirtual org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler.preventNonZeroExitCode() : void [7]
39 return
40 aload_0 [this]
41 getfield org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler.delegate : java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler [2]
44 ifnull 58
47 aload_0 [this]
48 getfield org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler.delegate : java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler [2]
51 aload_1 [thread]
52 aload_2 [exception]
53 invokeinterface java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread, java.lang.Throwable) : void [8] [nargs: 3]
58 return
Line numbers:
[pc: 0, line: 39]
[pc: 18, line: 40]
[pc: 27, line: 41]
[pc: 35, line: 42]
[pc: 39, line: 44]
[pc: 40, line: 46]
[pc: 47, line: 47]
[pc: 58, line: 49]
Local variable table:
[pc: 0, pc: 59] local: this index: 0 type: org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler
[pc: 0, pc: 59] local: thread index: 1 type: java.lang.Thread
[pc: 0, pc: 59] local: exception index: 2 type: java.lang.Throwable
Stack map table: number of frames 4
[pc: 27, same]
[pc: 39, same]
[pc: 40, same]
[pc: 58, same]
Method Parameters:
thread
exception

// Method descriptor #50 (Ljava/lang/Thread;)Z
// Stack: 2, Locals: 6
private boolean isJvmExiting(java.lang.Thread exceptionThread);
0 aload_0 [this]
1 invokevirtual org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler.getAllThreads() : java.lang.Thread[] [9]
4 astore_2
5 aload_2
6 arraylength
7 istore_3
8 iconst_0
9 istore 4
11 iload 4
13 iload_3
14 if_icmpge 53
17 aload_2
18 iload 4
20 aaload
21 astore 5 [thread]
23 aload 5 [thread]
25 aload_1 [exceptionThread]
26 if_acmpeq 47
29 aload 5 [thread]
31 invokevirtual java.lang.Thread.isAlive() : boolean [10]
34 ifeq 47
37 aload 5 [thread]
39 invokevirtual java.lang.Thread.isDaemon() : boolean [11]
42 ifne 47
45 iconst_0
46 ireturn
47 iinc 4 1
50 goto 11
53 iconst_1
54 ireturn
Line numbers:
[pc: 0, line: 52]
[pc: 23, line: 53]
[pc: 45, line: 54]
[pc: 47, line: 52]
[pc: 53, line: 57]
Local variable table:
[pc: 23, pc: 47] local: thread index: 5 type: java.lang.Thread
[pc: 0, pc: 55] local: this index: 0 type: org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler
[pc: 0, pc: 55] local: exceptionThread index: 1 type: java.lang.Thread
Stack map table: number of frames 3
[pc: 11, append: {java.lang.Thread[], int, int}]
[pc: 47, same]
[pc: 53, chop 3 local(s)]
Method Parameters:
exceptionThread

// Method descriptor #53 ()[Ljava/lang/Thread;
// Stack: 2, Locals: 4
protected java.lang.Thread[] getAllThreads();
0 aload_0 [this]
1 invokespecial org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler.getRootThreadGroup() : java.lang.ThreadGroup [12]
4 astore_1 [rootThreadGroup]
5 bipush 32
7 anewarray java.lang.Thread [13]
10 astore_2 [threads]
11 aload_1 [rootThreadGroup]
12 aload_2 [threads]
13 invokevirtual java.lang.ThreadGroup.enumerate(java.lang.Thread[]) : int [14]
16 istore_3 [count]
17 iload_3 [count]
18 aload_2 [threads]
19 arraylength
20 if_icmpne 40
23 aload_2 [threads]
24 arraylength
25 iconst_2
26 imul
27 anewarray java.lang.Thread [13]
30 astore_2 [threads]
31 aload_1 [rootThreadGroup]
32 aload_2 [threads]
33 invokevirtual java.lang.ThreadGroup.enumerate(java.lang.Thread[]) : int [14]
36 istore_3 [count]
37 goto 17
40 aload_2 [threads]
41 iload_3 [count]
42 invokestatic java.util.Arrays.copyOf(java.lang.Object[], int) : java.lang.Object[] [15]
45 checkcast java.lang.Thread[] [16]
48 areturn
Line numbers:
[pc: 0, line: 61]
[pc: 5, line: 62]
[pc: 11, line: 63]
[pc: 17, line: 64]
[pc: 23, line: 65]
[pc: 31, line: 66]
[pc: 40, line: 68]
Local variable table:
[pc: 0, pc: 49] local: this index: 0 type: org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler
[pc: 5, pc: 49] local: rootThreadGroup index: 1 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
[pc: 11, pc: 49] local: threads index: 2 type: java.lang.Thread[]
[pc: 17, pc: 49] local: count index: 3 type: int
Stack map table: number of frames 2
[pc: 17, append: {java.lang.ThreadGroup, java.lang.Thread[], int}]
[pc: 40, same]

// Method descriptor #62 ()Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;
// Stack: 1, Locals: 2
private java.lang.ThreadGroup getRootThreadGroup();
0 invokestatic java.lang.Thread.currentThread() : java.lang.Thread [17]
3 invokevirtual java.lang.Thread.getThreadGroup() : java.lang.ThreadGroup [18]
6 astore_1 [candidate]
7 aload_1 [candidate]
8 invokevirtual java.lang.ThreadGroup.getParent() : java.lang.ThreadGroup [19]
11 ifnull 22
14 aload_1 [candidate]
15 invokevirtual java.lang.ThreadGroup.getParent() : java.lang.ThreadGroup [19]
18 astore_1 [candidate]
19 goto 7
22 aload_1 [candidate]
23 areturn
Line numbers:
[pc: 0, line: 72]
[pc: 7, line: 73]
[pc: 14, line: 74]
[pc: 22, line: 76]
Local variable table:
[pc: 0, pc: 24] local: this index: 0 type: org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler
[pc: 7, pc: 24] local: candidate index: 1 type: java.lang.ThreadGroup
Stack map table: number of frames 2
[pc: 7, append: {java.lang.ThreadGroup}]
[pc: 22, same]

// Method descriptor #65 ()V
// Stack: 1, Locals: 1
protected void preventNonZeroExitCode();
0 iconst_0
1 invokestatic java.lang.System.exit(int) : void [20]
4 return
Line numbers:
[pc: 0, line: 80]
[pc: 4, line: 81]
Local variable table:
[pc: 0, pc: 5] local: this index: 0 type: org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler

// Method descriptor #67 (Ljava/lang/Thread;)V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 2
static void setup(java.lang.Thread thread);
0 aload_0 [thread]
1 invokevirtual java.lang.Thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler() : java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler [21]
4 astore_1 [handler]
5 aload_1 [handler]
6 instanceof org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler [22]
9 ifne 26
12 new org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler [22]
15 dup
16 aload_1 [handler]
17 invokespecial org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler) [23]
20 astore_1 [handler]
21 aload_0 [thread]
22 aload_1 [handler]
23 invokevirtual java.lang.Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler) : void [24]
26 return
Line numbers:
[pc: 0, line: 84]
[pc: 5, line: 85]
[pc: 12, line: 86]
[pc: 21, line: 87]
[pc: 26, line: 89]
Local variable table:
[pc: 0, pc: 27] local: thread index: 0 type: java.lang.Thread
[pc: 5, pc: 27] local: handler index: 1 type: java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
Stack map table: number of frames 1
[pc: 26, append: {java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler}]
Method Parameters:
thread

// Method descriptor #65 ()V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 0
static void exitCurrentThread();
0 new org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler$SilentExitException [3]
3 dup
4 aconst_null
5 invokespecial org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler$SilentExitException(org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler$1) [25]
8 athrow
Line numbers:
[pc: 0, line: 92]

Inner classes:
[inner class info: #28 org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/SilentExitExceptionHandler$1, outer class info: #0
inner name: #0, accessflags: 4104 static],
[inner class info: #3 org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/SilentExitExceptionHandler$SilentExitException, outer class info: #22 org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/SilentExitExceptionHandler
inner name: #30 SilentExitException, accessflags: 10 private static],
[inner class info: #27 java/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler, outer class info: #13 java/lang/Thread
inner name: #32 UncaughtExceptionHandler, accessflags: 1545 public abstract static]
}
```

test debug with 4 breackpoints:
[image: test debug with 4 breackpoints]
[image: test debug with 4 breackpoints]

Comment: So it appears that jar does not contain any source code, just compiled class files. Is there a separate jar containing the source available?

Comment: I imported 'spring-boot-devtools-2.7.4-sources.jar', but nothing has changed

Comment: You have to tell Eclipse what that is for by setting it as the "Source attachment" for the main jar in the Classpath in the Libraries section of the Build Path.

Comment: but now I have Class file editor source not found ArrayList.class .........ArrayList<E>.forEach(Consumer<? super E>) line 1511 ..........The ArrayList class is part of the java.lang.Object

Comment: I tried to point to the source it already has in the jdk, but it doesn't work

Comment: SOLUTION: I removed the jdk from the workspace, went to its installation folder on disk C, unzipped the src.zip folder and re-added it to the workspace and it worked